# EmberJS: Computed property awareness of dependent keys

Tags: ember.js

Let's suppose I have an object that has this structure: 
`{ filters: [{ params: { value: ["abc"] }] }`.

How can I write a computed property that is aware of changes to the `value` property? For example, let's say we take one of the filters and do `set(filter, 'params.value', ["abc", "123"])`. I've been trying with `computed('filters.@each.params.value.[]', ...)` but it isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I guess I know how to help you. First of all it seems to be impossible to have a computed property with [deeply nested keys after](https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember/blob/master/docs/rules/no-deeply-nested-dependent-keys-with-each.md) `@each`. That's why in order to make this work one has to split it. Something like this:

```
export default Component.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    this.o = {filters: [{params: {value: ["abc"]}}]};
  },

  params: computed('o.filters.@each.params', function () {
    return this.o.filters.mapBy('params');
  }),

  paramsValue: computed('params.@each.value', function () {
    let aaa = this.params; // it seems like we need to reference the params anyhow
    return JSON.stringify(this.o);
  }),

  @action
  changeClassic() {
    let filter = this.o.filters[0];
    set(filter, 'params.value', ['abc', '123']);
  }

});
```

I also tried to solve the same problem in case of a glimmer component with `@tracked`. There I had to [use a separate class](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/tracked-properties/#toc_plain-old-javascript-objects-pojos) and make the `value` field tracked:

```
class ValueHandler {
  @tracked value;

  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

export default class DeepObjectTestComponent extends Component {

  @tracked o = {filters: [{params: new ValueHandler('abc')}]};

  // so here I don't need an intermediate computed (hope this works for a more complicated  scenario
  get paramsValue() {
    let aaa = this.o.filters[0].params.value;
    return JSON.stringify(this.o);
  }

  @action
  changeGlimmer() {
    let filter = this.o.filters[0];
    // set(filter, 'params.value', ['abc', '123']);
    filter.params.value = ['abc', '123'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do the same. You have flatten your classes with glimmer tracking. To nest you have to create a class within a class. It feels a bit backwards but I'm sure there are technical performance reasons.